# Indices in a sum of series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

how I can express correctely in one serie the following expresion 
$$\sum _{(k=-20) (k\neq 0)}^{20} -\frac{2 \left(\frac{3}{2} \pi  \csc \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 \pi  k+\pi )\right) \text{sech}\left(\frac{1}{3} \pi  (2 k+1)\right)-\frac{2}{3} \pi  \sec (\pi  k) \text{sech}\left(\frac{3}{4} \pi  (2 k+1)\right)\right)}{\pi ^2 k (2 k+1)^3}$$ normaly I must to divide the expresion in two series from k=-infinite to -1 and for 1 to Infinity to avoid the zero 
thanks

Comment: `Sum[If[k != 0, f[k], 0], {k, -20, 20}]`

Comment: How about `Sum[f[k] + f[-k], {k, 20}]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to explicitly define the index

```
ks = Join[Range[-5, -3], Range[-1, 1], Range[3, 5]]
Sum[f[i], {i, ks}]
```

> f[-5] + f[-4] + f[-3] + f[-1] + f[0] + f[1] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5]

One can also use a conditional expression as suggested by @coolwater, but it will consume more time

```
RepeatedTiming[Sum[If[k != 0, f[k], 0], {k, -200, 200}]][[1]]
```

> 0.0004

```
RepeatedTiming[ks = Join[Range[-200, -1], Range[1, 200]]; 
               Sum[f[i], {i, ks}]][[1]]
```

> 0.000221

Comment: thanks Sumit but it is possible do it more elegant as the example above

Comment: I am not sure what kind of elegance you are looking for, but my feeling is it might cost some extra time. Anyway, wait for some better answer :)